# Get layout metrics in MathJax

Tags: mathjax

I'm wondering if it's possible to extract the metrics for the baseline of the `mrow` elements in a rendered mathjax equation, specificically using the SVG Output Jax.

For example, [the mml-sample page](https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/test/sample-mml.html) (raw version [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mathjax/MathJax/master/test/sample-mml.html) ) has a block element with 3 `mrow` elements, and I'm wondering if it's possible to extract the position (preferably, the x and y positions of endpoints) of the baselines of these elements.

Comment: If you are after some kind of built-in API then the answer is no. You can obviously calculate the equation's baseline from height and vertical-align but there is no subexpression API.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the short answer: Fork a copy of Mathjax and then set the [removable flag on the 'g' elements](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/blob/master/unpacked/jax/output/SVG/jax.js#L866) to `false`, to prevent the `<g>` elements that represent the nesting in the original MML from being removed -- an by doing this the origin of the baseline can be read from the `transform="translate(...)"` and `transform="scale(...)"` attributes

Next, export any other metrics, such as:

- `svg.H`: Height above the baseline of the entire (sub) expression (un-scaled)
- `svg.D`: Depth below the baseline of the entire (sub) expression (un-scaled)
- `svg.w`: Width of the rendered expression (un-scaled)
- `svg.r`: right margin (un-scaled)
- `svg.l`: left margin (un-scaled)
- `svg.scale`: Scaling factor

[here](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/blob/master/unpacked/jax/output/SVG/jax.js#L876) and [here](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/blob/master/unpacked/jax/output/SVG/jax.js#L887) with something like:

```
svg.element.setAttribute("fm",
    "{D:" + SVG.Fixed(svg.D,2) + 
    ",H:" + SVG.Fixed(svg.H,2) + 
    ",r:" + SVG.Fixed(svg.r,2) + 
    ",l:" + SVG.Fixed(svg.l,2) + 
    ",w:" + SVG.Fixed(svg.w,2) + 
    ",s:" + SVG.Fixed(svg.scale,5) + 
    "}");
```

Optionally, to reduce the extent of unnecessary nesting, change `svg.removeable` to `(svg.removeable || svg.element.nodeName === "g")` in [this `if` statement](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/blob/master/unpacked/jax/output/SVG/jax.js#L877)